# How to convert date from yyyyMMdd format to mm-dd-yyyy format

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format

I want to convert a string which contains the date in `yyyyMMdd` format to `mm-dd-yyyy` DateTime format.  How do I get it?

Answer (score 47):

```
var dateString = "20050802";
var date = myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString,
                                    "yyyyMMdd",
                                    System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public static DateTime ConvertDate(string date, string pattern)
{
    DateTime retval = DateTime.MinValue;
    if (System.DateTime.TryParseExact(date, pattern, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out retval))
       return retval;

    // Could not convert date..
    return DateTime.MinValue;
}


DateTime myDate = ConvertDate("20101230", "yyyyMMdd");
```

Comment: string dateString=19850121; //in yyyyMMdd format                                                              string oldFormat=yyyyMMdd ;                                                DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, oldFormat, provider); //MM/dd/yyyy format

Answer (score 1):

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-UK");   

string dateString = "19850121"; //in yyyyMMdd format 

string oldFormat = "yyyyMMdd"; 

DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, oldFormat, provider); //MM/dd/yyyyformat
```