# Convert date yyyyMMdd to system.datetime format

Tags: c#, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to convert date from yyyyMMdd format to mm-dd-yyyy fomrat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712335/how-to-convert-date-from-yyyymmdd-format-to-mm-dd-yyyy-fomrat)

I have a `string` which contains date in yyyyMMdd format. I want to convert that date into system date format using `ConvertTo.DateTime()` method or any other simple method.

```
string value = "19851231";  //yyyyMMdd

DateTime dateTime = 1985/12/31;
```

Comment: Your question was already answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712335/how-to-convert-date-from-yyyymmdd-format-to-mm-dd-yyyy-fomrat

Comment: Why ask the same question again? Does the code shown in the answers to your previous question not work? If so, can you tell us why?

Answer (score 152):

```
string time = "19851231";
DateTime theTime= DateTime.ParseExact(time,
                                        "yyyyMMdd",
                                        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                                        DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Answer (score 1):

have at look at the static methods `DateTime.Parse()` and `DateTime.TryParse()`. They will allow you to pass in your date string and a format string, and get a DateTime object in return.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fw7727c.aspx

Comment: Solved my problem. Thanks !