# String not valid as a datetime string - Convert "yyyyMMdd" to datetime

Tags: c#, datetime

I have strings in format of "yyyyMMdd".
I would like to convert them into DateTime with the format but I get an error that says the string is not valid as a DateTime string.
How can I do this?

Comment: What u hav tried??? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: -1, No research effort. There are already thousands of questions about that very same issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert string to DateTime in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592653/convert-string-to-datetime-in-c-sharp)

Comment: This is the exact duplicate but i cannot choose it since it's also a dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720468/c-net-convert-date-yyyymmdd-to-system-datetime-format ( Btw, i don't like this new "thinking" dup-system )

Comment: @TimSchmelter It's also certainly not off-topic; I don't like this new closing system in general. It costs too much _think time_ that people just don't invest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) to specify the format and invariant culture:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 4):

Try [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx)

```
DateTime dt;

DateTime.TryParseExact(textBox.Text, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt);
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact`:

```
string dateString = "20130701";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyyMMdd", null, DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked and answered before. But here is an example of working code:

```
string DateString = "20130701";
DateTime DT = DateTime.ParseExact(DateString, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Where `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` is a part of the System.Globalization namespace.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo(v=vs.71).aspx

Answer (score -2):

Break them into a format which DateTime.Parse will accept as valid. You could even use a regular expression to parse out the information

```
Regex format = new Regex("(?<year>^[0-9]{4})(?<month>[0-9]{2})(?<day>[0-9]{2})");
Match m = format.Match(inputString);
int year = int.Parse(m.Groups["year"].Value;
int month = int.Parse(m.Groups["month"].Value;
int day = int.Parse(m.Groups["day"].Value;
DateTime date = new DateTime(year, month, day);
```