# How do I convert and integer to datetime

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using ASP.NET Visual Basic.

I have an integer field in my database which I need to read as a date e.g. 20130813. But at the moment it says I cannot convert to datetime.

Is there a way to split the integer up into DD, MM, YYYY so I could even store those in variables to then use to create a date. Or a simple way of just converting to date.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Take a look at DateTime.TryParseExact.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to convert date from yyyyMMdd format to mm-dd-yyyy fomrat](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4712335/how-to-convert-date-from-yyyymmdd-format-to-mm-dd-yyyy-fomrat)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you're starting with a number, you could either convert it to a string and use DateTime.TryParseExact, or use a bit of integer arithmetic to split it up:

```
Dim n As Integer = 20130813
Dim yr As Integer = n \ 10000
Dim mon As Integer = (n - 10000 * yr) \ 100
Dim d As Integer = n Mod 100
Dim dt As New DateTime(yr, mon, d)
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
Dim provider As CultureInfo = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
Dim sData As String = "20130813" 
Dim myDate As Date = Date.ParseExact(sData, "yyyyMMdd", provider)
```

You can convert your number to string easily, if needed:

```
Dim myNum As Integer = 20130813
sData = myNum.ToString()
```

See [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Quicker:

```
Dim d As Date = Date.FromOADate(41498)
```

(from [Robert Shutt](https://www.experts-exchange.com/members/robert_schutt.html) in [experts-exchange.com](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28253989/VB-NET-convert-Integer-to-Date.html))

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub stringtodate(ByVal dateval As String)
    Dim yy As String
    Dim mm As String
    Dim dd As String
    Dim newdate As Date
    yy = dateval.Substring(0, 4)
    mm = dateval.Substring(4, 2)
    dd = dateval.Substring(6, 2)
    newdate =Convert.ToDateTime(dd & "/" & mm & "/" & yy)
    MsgBox(newdate.ToString())
End Sub
```

Comment: In the line `newdate =dd & "/" & mm & "/" & yy` you are assigning a String to a DateTime. This will not compile with Option Strict On. Also, the OP is supplying an integer, not a string.