# How to Convert Integer to Date?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to convert integer to date? I am using a datagridview where users can type a combinations of number (e.g 07191993) when in `editmode` then after the user is done editing, the program should format it in date (07-19-1993).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I convert and integer to datetime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18207611/how-do-i-convert-and-integer-to-datetime)

Answer (score 1):

To get a date from the number inputed by user :

```
Dim theDate = DateTime.ParseExact (input, "MMddyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) ' or some other specific CultureInfo / FormatProvider)
```

To display the date as wanted (if given FormatProvider doesn't do it by itself) :

```
Dim repr = theDate.ToString ("MM-dd-yyyy")
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an event for `CellEndEdit` of `datagridview` and put in this code

```
    Dim n As Integer = 'Datagridview cell value'
    Dim mon As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(n.ToString.Substring(0, 1))
    Dim dt As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(n.ToString.Substring(1, 2))
    Dim yr As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(n.ToString.Substring(3, 4))
    Dim dt1 As New DateTime(yr, mon, dt)
```

hope this helps.